# HTML CSS Elements coming over each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple search form. It has a search bar and a table. Table will get popluated after some search queries. But for me, these two element are coming over each other.

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Store Dashboard</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dashboard.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navigation">
<div class="container">
<span class="title">
<i class="fa fa-home"></i> Store Dashboard
</span>
<span class="search-control"  onclick="">
  Log Out <a style="font-family:fontawesomqe;"></a>
</span>
</div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
<div class="search-box" id="SBox">
    <input id="search" placeholder="Search..." type="text">
    <div class="also search-link" onclick="" id="searchclick"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Head 1</th>
        <th>Head 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Example 1</td>
        <td>Example 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Example 6</td>
        <td>Example 7</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie');
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
@import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');

*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
body{
    background-color:#eee;
}
.navigation {
    background-color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #c8c8c8;
    line-height:52px;
    color:#62bb49;
}
.container {
    width:760px;
    margin:auto;
    position: relative;
}
.title {
    font-family:'Cookie';
    font-size:32px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.search-control{
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #bbb;
}
.search-control:hover {color:#686868;}
.fa-home {
    font-size:22px;
}
.search-box {
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    top:48px;
    height:48px;
    transition:opacity 0.4s linear ,visibility 0.4s linear 0s;
}
.search-box > #search {
    width:640px;
    height:48px;
    border-radius:6px 0px 0px 6px;
    box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #ddd;
}
input , input:focus {
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    background-color:none;
    outline: 0;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    color:#bbb;
    padding:0px 12px;
}
.also {
    font-family:'fontawesome';
    color:#bbb;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#fff;
    height:48px;
    width:48px;
    line-height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-left:1px solid #ddd;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #ddd;
}
.search-link:hover {color:#686868;}
.setting {
    border-radius:0px 6px 6px 0px;
    margin-left:48px;
    font-size:18px;
}
.setting:hover {color:#686868;}


.flat-table {
    display: block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 115%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: auto;
}

th {
    background-color: rgb(112, 196, 105);
    color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
td {
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    color: rgb(111, 111, 111);
    padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

Can anybody suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow, If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `position: relative` on the element `.search-box` and then set `top: 48px`. This moves the search box down to the space occupied by the table.

Instead, use `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` to add space between these elements.

Comment: Thanks. You rock :)

Answer (score 0):

At your `.search-box` you have `top: 48px` change it to `margin-top: 48px;`

If you wanted the element to have no effect on the surrounding elements, you'd use positioning (absolute, relative) and the top, bottom, left and right.

If you want your element to push away or close to other surrounding elements use margin.

```
.search-box {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  transition: opacity 0.4s linear, visibility 0.4s linear 0s;
}
```

```css
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie');
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
@import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #c8c8c8;
  line-height: 52px;
  color: #62bb49;
}

.container {
  width: 760px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Cookie';
  font-size: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-control {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #bbb;
}

.search-control:hover {
  color: #686868;
}

.fa-home {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.search-box {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  transition: opacity 0.4s linear, visibility 0.4s linear 0s;
}

.search-box > #search {
  width: 640px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #ddd;
}

input,
input:focus {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: none;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 0px 12px;
}

.also {
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  color: #bbb;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #ddd;
}

.search-link:hover {
  color: #686868;
}

.setting {
  border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 0px;
  margin-left: 48px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.setting:hover {
  color: #686868;
}

.flat-table {
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 115%;
  overflow: auto;
  width: auto;
}

th {
  background-color: rgb(112, 196, 105);
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  color: rgb(111, 111, 111);
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Store Dashboard</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dashboard.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navigation">
<div class="container">
<span class="title">
<i class="fa fa-home"></i> Store Dashboard
</span>
<span class="search-control"  onclick="">
  Log Out <a style="font-family:fontawesomqe;"></a>
</span>
</div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
<div class="search-box" id="SBox">
    <input id="search" placeholder="Search..." type="text">
    <div class="also search-link" onclick="" id="searchclick"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Head 1</th>
        <th>Head 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Example 1</td>
        <td>Example 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Example 6</td>
        <td>Example 7</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```